# Best directory for shared scripts

Tags: scripting, directory-structure, conventions

What is the conventional directory to keep shared scripts that might be used by more than one user?

I've read through [this overview](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEUSRHIERARCHY) of the standard file system hierarchy, but it doesn't seem to recommend a location for storing shared scripts.  Creating a /opt/scripts directory seems like a reasonable option, but I'd like to know if there is a standard UNIX convention for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe it's `/usr/local/bin/` - it's for installing custom, not maintained by package manager executables.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is platform dependent.  On OpenBSD, for example, all 3rd party software from packages are installed in /usr/local/bin.  So, while it's probably the proper place for your own shared executable scripts as well, it's not always for "not maintained by package manager executables"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the purpose... but maybe /usr/bin is good place for most user programs. OPT is intended to have third party software.

Answer (score 0):

Make a directory `bin` in `/usr/local/share`.